# Mosaic dataset gives me some blocks

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, imagery, mosaic-dataset

I am trying to mosaic NAIP into mosaic dataset and ended up like this with the block.

How do I remove the blocks ?

[image]

Does anybody have a suggest for me to fix them ?

I am using ArcGIS 10.1 SP 3 and I also use the Mosaic Dataset.

Comment: Is there data covering them in the original? Perhaps the NoData value isn't set properly in those datasets causing 0,0,0 to overwrite underlying (earlier) rasters. You can mosaic with the 'maximum' option but be careful because this can cause serious issues in overlap areas.

Comment: Yes, I did set No Data as 0,0,0 .

Comment: Is there actually data there - is it very dark? are the black areas 0,0,0 or 1,1,1 (or another near-black)? Do you have the tile data areas as feature data?

Comment: It was 0,0,0 and then tried 1,1,1 did not work. I think the first time when I moasic two imagery I set them to 0,0,0 and then adding rasters and that was when they got black areaas.

Comment: Yes I have them the footprint here if that is what you mean ?

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I also post this the same from earlier this morning....see that the top one was the first step I did and then add a few NAIP imagery to it..https://geonet.esri.com/thread/122737

Comment: I think I got figured it out !

Comment: If so, please answer your own question so we can all see the solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21610/discussion-between-probert-and-michael-miles-stimson).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before using the Moasic Dataset, I did not have the confidence to perform them until yesterday and gave a try.

Now I have play it around and now I had to figure it out...

Not sure the workflow is but here is what I did:

Create mosaic dataset

add rasters

build footprints

build seamlines

Remove the dataset from ArcMap

Run build overviews on the dataset within the Catalog

Bring dataset to ArcMap to check...

[image]

This is the another one I am using NAIP 2014 It looks good but there's some black gaps on the right lower corner ...

I am not sure HOW to fix that ..should I re run the footprints or seamlines to correct it ?

The white hole you see is a military area that is restricted to the public...

Comment: It could just be in the overviews, zooming in may rectify it. What resampling method did you use for the overviews? Cubic can do funny things, I think Bilinear would be the best for this.

Comment: I didnt modify the resolution. How can I change from NN to Bilinear ?

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson  - Never mind They are already in Bilinear